# Array parameter for TADOQuery in Delphi 2010

Tags: sql, arrays, delphi, parameter-passing, tadoquery

I need to execute a simple query:

`SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Id IN (:ids)`

Obviously, it returns the set of records which have their primary key 'Id' in the given list. How can I pass an array of integer IDs into ADOQuery.Parameters for parameter 'ids'? I have tried VarArray - it does not work. Parameter 'ids' has FieldType = ftInteger by default, if it matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no parameter type that can be used to pass a list of values to `in`. Unfortunately, this is one of the shortcomings of parameterized SQL.

You'll have to build the query from code to either generate the list of values, or generate a list of parameters which can then be filled from code. That's because you *can* pass each value as a different parameter, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Id IN (:id1, :id2, :id3)
```

But since the list will probably have a variable size, you'll have to alter the SQL to add parameters. In that case it is just as easy to generate the list of values, although parametereized queries may be cached better, depending on which DB you use.

Answer (score 0):

The IN param just takes a comma separated string of values like (1,2,3,4,5)  so I assume you set the datatype to ftstring and just build the string and pass that...? Not tried it but it's what I *would* try...

Comment: That doesn't work. Common pitfall. It takes a comma separated list of values, but this list is not a (single) string.

Comment: OK you seem to be correct, after an hour or so I give up, there does not seem to be a way, even by the devious means I have been trying! Having said that a down vote for making a suggestion (that I said I had not tried) and falling into a pre-prepared pit seems a trifle harsh!)

Comment: Well, it's often considered impolite to post an un-tried solution, although I personally don't care much about that, as long as the answer points you in the right direction. But in this case, the answer is plain wrong, and thus as the downvote button title says: "This answer is not useful". But if it's any consolation: downvoting costs me points too. ;-)